# How can I choose multiple selections in tableview and save them? If I move back I want see what I selected before and change it

Tags: uitableview, swift3

In Swift 3, how can I choose multiple selections in a tableview and save them? If I move back I want see what I selected before and change it!
I am using "didSelectRowAt IndexPath" and "didDeselectRowAt IndexPath".

When I open tableview and choose rows, all is OK. I can make my choices and go to the next ViewController. But when I move back to TableView I didn't see my selected rows and can't change my selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can store the indexpath of your tableviewcell in one array,
>   iterate it, get the `UITableViewCell` instance set the accessory type to checkmark.

```
for index in indexpaths {
 let cell = table.cellForRow(at: index)
 cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
 //For selecting rows of already selected one
 tablView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: 
 .bottom)
}
```

> Note:- set `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true` if you want to
>   allow multiple selection.

Comment: I did it! But how I can change my selection?

Comment: Try that tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

Comment: I change my question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337531/in-swift-3-how-can-i-choose-multiple-selections-in-a-tableview-and-save-them-i